# Cluster wide connection resources management in Ignite, using Hikari

Tags: java, ignite, hikaricp

How can I manage resources on ignite.

Given the application i am developing, i have a few connections that i used to keep, (JDBC/SAP/others). 
I used to keep all the connections in a pool and manage them using HIKARI. 
Now given that now I can have a cluster of machines using ignite, what method can I use, so that I can distribute the connections across the nodes.

Ignite doesn't provide this mechanism out of the box.

I have thought of using services as a container for these connections, but then the management of connection is an extra overhead. As good as reinventing the wheel.

Hikari doesn't have any cluster management features and hence is limited to single node resource.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a chance to take a look at [JDBC client node driver](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-jdbc-client-node-driver)? It should handle distributing the queries between nodes.

Comment: This will not help, as I do not want to create the connections on every node. Connections to certain legacy applications can be heavy and might take more than a minute to create a connection. Hence I need to maintain a pool. Though this pool can be distributed, I would prefer a single or a set of nodes to hold these resources rather than spread them across.

Comment: You can use HikariCP pool with the JDBC client node driver, the only thing that should be considered is that every connection will go via the same internal Ignite node used by the driver, but it's OK since this driver was designed with such case in mind.  
With the thin mode JDBC driver, it's up to you how you provide a fallback in case if the target node goes down. There are some solutions that allow for using multiple datasources with a fallback logic, for example, some app servers provide such capability, as well you could take a look at [HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.org/doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

SAP Data Services, as of 4.2 SP2, now supports the use of JDBC drivers as a data source. This capability has been implemented through a new adapter type, JDBC.

To add a JDBC adapter you use the Data Services Administration Console, browse to adapter instances, choose your job server and then select Adapter Configuration.

[SAP Data Services and JDBC](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/04/sap-data-services-and-jdbc/)

SAP HANA provides a driver that enables Java applications to connect to the SAP HANA database with the JDBC application programming interface (API).

[Connect to SAP HANA via JDBC](https://help.sap.com/viewer/52715f71adba4aaeb480d946c742d1f6/2.0.00/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html)